# Where can I find settings for Sharepoint Addin VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint

does someone know where to find the deployment target settings for vs2008 when using sharepoint dev addin?
Changed the web server and cannot find where to change the deployment target in my solution... did have a look in .sln and .csproj but no settings found

Get reasonable error message saying it cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:8010 which is correct

Answer (score 1):

As strange as it may seems, you set the target URL in the Debug tab in the properties page for the project.
Change the Start Action-> "Start browser with URL:" setting.

Hope this helps.